# Persist non-primitive data in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am creating a program that needs to interact with a database. It's a bare-bones inventory management system, so the entities are 'Item' and 'Patron'.

Edit: This is a Vaadin application using Spring boot and spring data JPA

First I will start with my 2 classes and omit getters/setters for brevity.

```
@Table(name="item")
@Entity 
public class Item implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long barcode;
    @NotNull
    private String name, type;
    @NotNull
    private boolean isAvailable;
    @Nullable
    private boolean isLate;
    @Nullable
    private String notes;
    @Nullable
    private Patron currentPatron;
    @Nullable
    private Patron[] history;
    @Nullable
    private Date checkOutDate, dueDate;

    public Item() {}

    public Item(long barcode, String name, String type, boolean isAvailable) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
    }

    public Item(long barcode, String name, String type, String notes, boolean isAvailable) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
    }

    public Item(long barcode, String name, String type, String notes, boolean isAvailable, Date checkOutDate, Date dueDate, boolean isLate, Patron currentPatron, Patron[] history) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
        this.checkOutDate = checkOutDate;
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
        this.isLate = isLate;
        this.currentPatron = currentPatron;
        this.history = history;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="patron")
public class Patron {
    @Id
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String name, email;
    @Nullable
    private Item[] checkedOutItems;
    @Nullable
    private List<Item> itemHistory;
    @Nullable
    private boolean owesFines;
    @Nullable
    private int finesOwed;

    public Patron() {}

    public Patron(long id, String name, String email, boolean owesFines) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.owesFines = owesFines;
    }

    public Patron(long id, String name, String email, Item[] checkedOutItems, List<Item> itemHistory, boolean owesFines, int finesOwed) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.checkedOutItems = checkedOutItems;
        this.itemHistory = itemHistory;
        this.owesFines = owesFines;
        this.finesOwed = finesOwed;
    }
```

In practice the Patron Object is instantiated by scanning their campus ID with a MSR. Then that data populates the name, email and ID fields of the patron class.

When checking out an item, the patron would first swipe their card with the MSR (the system would confirm they are in the DB, add them if not).
After their magnetic strip is scanned, the QR code for the item they want is scanned so we can tie that item to them.

When an item is checked out to a patron, we need to get their **id**, **name** and **email** from the Patron table and then populate the rest of its variables: `check_out_date`, `due_date`, etc.

A patron can check out many items, but only one item can be checked out to a patron. Does This establish a `OneToMany` relationship? Patron -> Item(

My thought process was as follows:

**For Patron Objects**
have an array of Items to store the barcode of the items they currently have.
have an arraylist of items to store info about what patron had it and when `List<Item> history`, that way the code is as simple as `history.addToFront(something)`

**For Item Objects**
have a Patron object to see who has it 
have an arraylist of patrons to see all the times it was checked out

Q1: Is it redundant to have an array and a list as instance data for both classes?

Q1.2: Are an array of objects and a list of objects even appropriate data structures for a scenario like this?

Q1.3: Is there a difference in using `javax.persistence.*;` and `org.springframework.data.annotation.*;` for something like ID and is there a difference between `import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;` and `import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;`

Q2: Does this produce a `OneToMany` relationship between Patron and Items?

Q3: In order to achieve this, I believe I need some additional tables in my database. I was thinking something like this: (And I realize I will need to include the appropriate spring annotations when implementing the new schema)

**Item table**

```
create table item(barcode int(10) primary key, name varchar(64) not null, type varchar(64) not null, availability boolean, is_late boolean, note varchar(255), check_out_date Datetime, due_date Datetime); #foreign keys for currentPatron and Patron History
```

**Patron table**

```
create table patron(id int(10) primary key, name varchar(64) not null, email varchar(64) not null, owes_fines boolean, fines_owed int); #foreign key to item table?
```

**Patron_Item_History table**
: This would pull **id, name, email** from the patron table, and then **id, check_out_date, due_date** from the item table?

**Item_Patron_History table**: Similar structure to the above table?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you tryed one file per class ? Spring use a lot reflexivity. That may be the issue. This looks like an exam, isn't it ?

Comment: No, it's for work. Also patron and item are their own separate classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK here goes,

I am assuming you're building you application with Spring Boot, Hibernate as your ORM and probably some kind or relational database (MySQL).

Regarding db design:

Yes the Patreon object here is the owning entity with a OneToMany relation to the Item entity (since one Patreon may have N objects). 
Your Patreon entity could do with the following redesing:

1) Try to use non-primitive types especially for table keys (long id -> Long id).

2) Lose the array of checkedOutItems as well as the itemHistory list. First of all relations should be modelled using collections and not arrays. Secondly you don't need those two. 
You'll never store the checkedOutItems nor the itemHistory this way. Instead create a `List<Item> items` that will store the Patreon items while describing the relation (here are some examples: http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)

3) Again with the Item entity you need to lose the array of history. The only thing you need there is a reference to the owning entity (Patreon in this case) thus completing the ManyToOne side of the relation.

4) Note that Date fields should be annotated with `@Temporal` also providing the correct type (you can read up for more).

5) Item class in general should do with a redesign.

5) After all the above are in place and assuming you're using Spring, you can create a Repository with which you can query a Patreon object thus retrieving an object along with it's related entities (Items).

Regarding your questions:

Q1: Yes it see. See above for more.

Q1.2: No arrays are not. Lists or better yet Sets are more suited.

Q1.3: Yes there is. The first one a JPA annotation used in relational
   databases while the second one is Spring Data specific annotation
   used by databases and frameworks that are not of this type
   (relational) or do not have a standard persistence API defined (like
   JPA). For the NonNull and NotNull are roughly the same with the first
   one actually supersetting the latter one (something that is done
   often). The only difference I see is the target. You can read for
   more here:
   https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/NonNull.html
   https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html

Q2: Yes there is. See above.

Q3: With a bit of clever desing I do not see the need for more, but
   hey If you feel it'll help you, why not. Just don't overkill the
   desingn and it's complexity

Comment: Thanks for the great response, unfortunately this brings up more questions :)
What is the advantage to use Long over long? As for tracking a history of items what would be a sane method of doing so? I've modified my entities to lose the array data. Correct me if I am wrong, but since its a OneToMany relation the List<item> loads the collection of items that are referenced by the patron?
Is an inner join applicable or would I need to create a new table referencing values from item/patron as needed? Ty.

Comment: Long is an Object and can be null. long is a primitive. It can't be null.

Comment: @GweltazNiquel yes but in the context of a key in a table where the column definition is by default non-nullable and the value is auto generated and managed by the underlying ORM it doesn't make any matter whether it's `Long` or `long`.

Comment: You're true, tue ORM doesn't mind if it's Long or long but if you pass a Long which is null, then it will fire an exception as there is a not null constraint in the underlying database. Autogeneration strategy is not a constraint neither, it doesn't mean you can't set it otherway...

Comment: @GweltazNiquel yes as long as the column definitions is non nullable otherwise it should go through fine. To be perfectly honest I do prefer the exception to be thrown rather than fall-back to the default value of the primitive type. Beside this could also lead to an integrity constraint exception.

Comment: Yes, It's really bad to use primitives. I agree.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time yesterday just thinking about a solution in my head.
I made the changes you mentioned to both classes. Long is an object and long is a primitive, you can serialize Long, is that why you recommended I use it instead?

I went on fiddle to test out my thoughts and here's what I came up with. It works as I want it to, but I would then need to implement it in my repository.. Something like repo.checkout(item, patron) should suffice? As for everything else, like populating a list for the client to view, is mainly java logic from here on out?

Anyway, Here's my solution!

```
create table item (
    barcode bigint not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(20) not null,
    type varchar(20) not null,
    is_available boolean not null,
    is_late boolean null,
    notes varchar(255) null,
    check_out_date datetime null,
    due_date datetime null
    #create index idx_barcode (barcode));

create table patron (
    trinity_id bigint not null primary key,
    name varchar(30) not null,
    email varchar(20) not null,
    owes_fines boolean not null,
    fines_owed int null
    #create index idx_trinity_id (trinity_id));

create table checked_out_items (
    ref_id bigint primary key auto_increment not null,
    patron_id bigint not null,
    item_id bigint not null,
    item_available boolean not null,
    item_check_out_date datetime null,
    item_due_date datetime null);

alter table checked_out_items
    add constraint fk_patron_id
    foreign key (patron_id) references patron(trinity_id),
    add constraint fk_item_id
    foreign key (item_id) references item(barcode)
    #add constraint fk_item_available
    #add constraint fk_check_out_date
    #add constraint fk_due_date
    #foreign key (item_available references item(is_available)
    #foreign key (item_check_out_date) references item(check_out_date)
    #foreign key (item_due_date) references item(due_date)
    on update cascade
    on delete cascade;     


insert into patron values(0000000,'Test Erino','test@erino.edu',0,null);
insert into item values(1,'Chromebook','Laptop',0,null,null,null,null);

insert into  checked_out_items(patron_id,item_id,item_available,item_check_out_date,item_due_date)
select patron.trinity_id,item.barcode,item.is_available,item.check_out_date,item.due_date
from patron
inner join item;
```

and lastly:

```
select * from item;
select * from patron;
select * from checked_out_items;
```

[image: Schema Setup]