# Spring Boot with Vaadin - using foreign keys

Tags: spring, vaadin

I am new to Spring Boot and Vaadin. I followed a tutorial to create CRUD pages for a phone book application however I am having trouble using foreign keys. I have a Contact table which has phone type (i.e. cell or home) as a foreign key - i.e. it is referenced to my PhoneType table. I am stuck on how  to populate the phone type from a drop down of values populated in my PhoneType table. Right now I am I have the following member variable in my Contact class

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="type")
private PhoneType phoneType;
```

And in my PhoneType class I have

```
@Column(name = "type")
private String phoneType;
```

However I am getting an error that says "Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement".

The rest of the application works well with the CRUD pages.

Comment: Isnt this more of a JPA problem than a spring or vaadin one? And please also provide the actual error or ramp up the logging to actually see it.  It might give a clue what is going wrong there.  Also when is this error happening.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in mySQL implementations you can't store actual objects **unless you use 8.0+ JSON data type**. SQL has no idea what a PhoneType is because it's an object and not a valid data type. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp

If you want to store actual objects you need to find a noSQL implementation that you like.

So your "Customer" class doesn't map to a table properly. You would need to make instance variables such as

```
String hasCellPhone, hasHomePhone; //etc for the options in your dropdown menu
```

instead of trying to put a phonetype object.

I asked almost the exact same question, I suggest you read this entire thread.
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/50879597/5468597

```
create table item (
    barcode bigint not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(20) not null,
    type varchar(20) not null,
    is_available boolean not null,
    is_late boolean null,
    notes varchar(255) null,
    check_out_date datetime null,
    due_date datetime null
    #create index idx_barcode (barcode));

create table patron (
    trinity_id bigint not null primary key,
    name varchar(30) not null,
    email varchar(20) not null,
    owes_fines boolean not null,
    fines_owed int null
    #create index idx_trinity_id (trinity_id));

create table checked_out_items (
    ref_id bigint primary key auto_increment not null,
    patron_id bigint not null,
    item_id bigint not null,
    item_available boolean not null,
    item_check_out_date datetime null,
    item_due_date datetime null);

alter table checked_out_items
    add constraint fk_patron_id
    foreign key (patron_id) references patron(trinity_id),
    add constraint fk_item_id
    foreign key (item_id) references item(barcode)
    #add constraint fk_item_available
    #add constraint fk_check_out_date
    #add constraint fk_due_date
    #foreign key (item_available references item(is_available)
    #foreign key (item_check_out_date) references item(check_out_date)
    #foreign key (item_due_date) references item(due_date)
    on update cascade
    on delete cascade;     


insert into patron values(0000000,'Test Erino','test@erino.edu',0,null);
insert into item values(1,'Chromebook','Laptop',0,null,null,null,null);

insert into  checked_out_items(patron_id,item_id,item_available,item_check_out_date,item_due_date)
select patron.trinity_id,item.barcode,item.is_available,item.check_out_date,item.due_date
from patron
inner join item;
```

and lastly:

```
select * from item;
select * from patron;
select * from checked_out_items;
```

[image: Schema Setup]

I won't post the java logic here. That's for you to read in the other thread.

Comment: Secondly, please include your class codes and the logic relating to the error. Is it a simple repo.save(item)? Do you have your schema setup correctly? Are your classes mapped as an entity?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question.

```
@ManyToOne (cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="phoneType_typeId")
private PhoneType phoneType;
```

And

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "typeId")
private Long id;
```